# Duplicate the physics body created via scenekit editor in code

Tags: swift, scenekit

I've been looking but unable to find how to duplicate the physics body I created in the scenekit editor to swift code.  I am looking to create a simple sphere shape around my dae model.  Here is a screen shot of the scenekit editor options.
Thanks

[image]

This code seems to be working for me but I'm not sure its the most optimal:

```
ball = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ball",recursively: true)!
let ballRadius = CGFloat(ball.boundingBox.max.x)
let ballShape = SCNSphere(radius: ballRadius)
ball.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ballShape, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type:SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.convexHull]))
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the shape property in the `SCNPhysicsBody` initializer to nil, it will automatically define a shape for the physics body. If your shape is just a ball, it should automatically set the physics body shape to be a sphere with the correct size.